# CSS Responsive Center Div

Tags: css, html, background, center

I would like to center some div which has background image. There is problem with response of this div, because if I set width on 80% and height on 80% the bg-image is not on center. I tried everything, but the picture can't just stand on center and if the browser is smaller or bigger this is very big problem.

So if you look at the picture

[image: block on center]

I want to make this white block responsive.

There is a little of css which I've already written, but for now is non-responsive:

```
top: 20%;
left: 30%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
background: url(images/background.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 750px 417px;
width: 750px;
height: 417px;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wanted to do the same thing 2 years ago, there's the solution:

Because you want it responsive, you may use the `@media` function in CSS3. Like this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    #div {
        top: 50%; /* IMPORTANT */
        left: 50%; /* IMPORTANT */
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        background: url(images/background.png) no-repeat center center;
        width: 750px;
        height: 417px;

        margin-top: -208.5px; /* HALF OF THE HEIGHT */
        margin-left: -375px; /* HALF OF THE WIDTH */
    }
}
```

The `max-width` you use is the maximum width of the device screen. You just copy it and change the `width, height, margin-left and margin-top` for the image. Also, you should change the `background` tag!

It will center the image on the page.

You can see an exemple at: [Créations MicroWeb - Carrières](http://www.careers.creationsmicroweb.com/). The image is totally centered even if you change the window side.

You can add `overflow: hidden;` on the `body` to make the page unscrollable when the resolution is too low. Like I did.

**EDIT**: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZKyE/1/)

Comment: Responsive like Bootstrap? That the background resize with the device screen?

Comment: Yes, if someone have smaller screen to show smaller background picture and if someone have bigger screen to show it only full width/height picture and nothing more.

Comment: The div is really centered now, but there is still problem with response. If I set max-width, this means that div will disappear if someone with too big screen open up this site. I need to make smaller image when someone with small screen visit my site, but I don't know how to do that. Do I need JavaScript to check width and height of it's browser?

Comment: Yeah, with `max-width` it will. But you can also use `min-width` like `@media (min-width: 1280px) { }` and any screen size over this will show the image selected.

Answer (score 20):

You could use CSS transform:

```
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 9):

Try with auto margins and display as table:

```
.your-class {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: table;
}
```

Comment: What is the theory behind this?

Comment: Why `display: table;`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `margin:0 auto;` to center a div horizontally as long as its width is less than that of the container div.

Comment: yes, but the div should be absolute positioned, so this is not option.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
img { max-width:100%; max-height:100%; margin:auto; }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.container{display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center}
```

Comment: Please add a description note. why this answer helps op.

Answer (score 1):

I have used `display: inline-block;` on element to center and `text-align: center;` on parent div.